# Unable to apply transition "reject" for workflow "unnamed"

Tags: symfony, symfony-workflows

I've some trouble with new symfony (3.2) workflows feature. It seems that I can only apply 'review' transition to the task.

```
$workflow->apply($task, 'review');
```

to see this code work.

[image]

With reject and review I always got this error.

[image]

Here the controller and the entity:

### Controller

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Workflow\DefinitionBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Workflow\MarkingStore\SingleStateMarkingStore;
use Symfony\Component\Workflow\Registry;
use Symfony\Component\Workflow\Transition;
use Symfony\Component\Workflow\Workflow;

class WorkflowController extends Controller
{
    /** @Route("/workflow", name="workflow") */
    public function indexAction(
        Request $request
    ) {
        $registry = new Registry();

        $definition = (new DefinitionBuilder())
            ->addPlaces(['drafted', 'reviewed', 'rejected', 'published'])
            ->addTransition(new Transition('review', 'drafted', 'reviewed'))
            ->addTransition(new Transition('publish', 'reviewed', 'published'))
            ->addTransition(new Transition('reject', 'reviewed', 'rejected'))
            ->build();

        $workflow = new Workflow(
            $definition,
            new SingleStateMarkingStore('state')
        );

        $task = new \AppBundle\Entity\Task();

        $workflow->apply($task, 'reject');

        $registry->add($workflow, \AppBundle\Entity\Task::class);

        return new Response(json_encode([
            'available_actions' => [
                'review'  => $workflow->can($task, 'review'),
                'publish' => $workflow->can($task, 'publish'),
                'reject'  => $workflow->can($task, 'reject'),
            ]]
        ));
    }
}
```

### Entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Task
{
    private $id;

    private $title;

    public $state;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

Can someone shoe me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can only apply `review` on newly created tasks as they are in the first status `drafted`. To publish or reject a task you first need to apply `review`, then either `reject` or `publish`:

```
$task = new Task();

// Place newly created task to reviewed status
$workflow->apply($task, 'reject');

// Then reject or publish
$workflow->apply($task, 'publish')
```

I will try to explain it. First, you define in what status can a task be:

```
->addPlaces(['drafted', 'reviewed', 'rejected', 'published'])
```

New tasks get `drafted` (the first one in the list) status since you omit setting value of `Task`s `state` property.

Next, you define the rules by which the task passes from one status to another (called `Transition`)

```
->addTransition(new Transition('review', 'drafted', 'reviewed'))
```

It's just defined transition (or action) called `review` which applicable only to `drafted` tasks and after performing on a task its status changes to `reviewed`.

So, to summarize, all newly created tasks first should be reviewed, then either published or rejected.